# What is the recommendation for ChatGPT-like answers?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

We have had a couple of users spring up over the last few days that seem to be posting ChatGPT/AI type answers that are vague enough to be useless, but close enough to be almost useful and are (generally) in well written English.

I'm pretty sure I saw something somewhere that ChatGPT answers weren't appreciated at SE in general, but I'm not able to find it again with a quick browse.

Presuming that I am correct that these answers aren't welcome here, what is the recommended way of handling them?

- Do we flag them as low quality?
- Do we simply down vote?
- Is some sort of "this appears to be ChatGPT content" comment appropriate?
- Where is the link to the "no ChatGPT" policy? I think that would be appropriate to copy/paste into a comment.

The last two suggestions would serve as a warning for a new user that the info here is marginal, at best.

At the rate these accounts seem to be coming, even some of our highest ranked users will start loosing privileges if we're expected to down vote them all.

Comment: The link to Meta StackOverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1 (I tried to post this as an answer, because it is an exact answer, link only because you asked for a link, but the system converted "trivial answer to comment").

Comment: Thanks, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. I've got a copy/paste comment now, linking to that. If others argue that it's not, I'll happily remove my comment.

Comment: New one: @techshqq - 3 answers so far, 99+% certain ChatGPT or equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say flag them. SE has decided they are against their policy, and what I've been seeing lately are spam users posting a few ChatGPT based answer to get past the first post review queue, or maybe to get people to click on their profile.

If it's only ChatGPT and nothing else done by the user, I delete the post with an explanation that it's not allowed. And if it's used to enable spam, they get booted.

Comment: Which flag option - "Mod attention" with a "ChatGPT" message for simplicity?

Comment: Yup, until they give us something better, that's probably the best method for now.